# Add event listeners with parameters to elements in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add event listeners to elements in a loop, but I'm struggling with getting the parameter to pass to the anonymous function correctly.

Here's an example of the html that I'm trying to apply the js to:

```
<button data-messagesend="Hello!">Send Hello</button>
<button data-messagesend="Goodbye!">Send Goodbye</button>
```

And here's the js:

```
// sendMsg function that will be applied to elements as an event listener
function sendMsg(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

//Get all elements that have the data-sendmessage property
elts=document.querySelectorAll('[data-messagesend]');

//Create global array for messages
var messages=[];

//Loop through elements and add an event listener to call sendMsg with it's massage
for(i=0;i<elts.length;i++) {

    //add element data-sendmessage value to messages array
    messages[i]=elts[i].dataset.messagesend;

    //add event listener
    elts[i].addEventListener('click',function(){sendMsg(messages[i]);}.bind(messages[i]),false);
}
```

it's the `//add event listener` line that I'm struggling with

I've also tried:

```
elts[i].addEventListener('click',function(){sendMsg(messages[i]);}.bind(messages,i),false);
```

and

```
elts[i].addEventListener('click',(function(msg){sendMsg(msg);})(messages[i]),false);
```

But it just returns `undefined` when the buttons are clicked.

Any help would be great :D

**Fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/to4nLz8L/

Comment: Use closure, `elts[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    (function (i) {
        sendMsg(messages[i]);
    }(i));
}, false);`

Comment: Still coming back undefined :(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/to4nLz8L/

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/d77jnqrt/

Comment: Ah, very nice, Thank you :D ... I almost went along with the 'possible duplicate' answer, and changing the `sendMsg` function to use `this.dataset.sendmessage` (Which I didn't really want to do). I think your answer actually answers my question more than the duplicate, which is more of a work-around than a fix. Stick it as an answer, I'm sure it'll help others :D

Comment: I cannot add answer as this question is marked as duplicate. You should add the answer.

Comment: Ah, yeah it doesn't let me add one either ... Cheers @Barmar Lol

Comment: @Tushar I've reopened, since you think this needs a different answer than the ones in the duplicate.

Comment: Stretch, you can add answer now. Let me know when you add it. @Barmar Although, it may look like this is not dup, the base concept is same so it is dup.

Comment: Okie dokie, thanks @Tushar

Comment: All done :D Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. The first, answered by @Tushar in the comments (And jFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d77jnqrt)), which uses the correct way to use enclosure:

```
// sendMsg function that will be applied to elements as an event listener
function sendMsg(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
}

//Get all elements that have the data-sendmessage property
elts = document.querySelectorAll('[data-messagesend]');

//Create global array for messages
var messages = [];

//Loop through elements and add an event listener to call sendMsg with it's massage
for (i = 0; i < elts.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        //add element data-sendmessage value to messages array
        messages[i] = elts[i].dataset.messagesend;
        console.log(messages);
        //add event listener
        elts[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            sendMsg(messages[i]);
        }, false);
    }(i));
}
```

And then the second way, referenced by @Barmar for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-issue), which changes the `sendMsg` function to get the dataset info:

```
// sendMsg function that will be applied to elements as an event listener
function sendMsg(msg) {
    msg=this.dataset.messagesend||msg;
    console.log(msg);
}

//Get all elements that have the data-sendmessage property
elts=document.querySelectorAll('[data-messagesend]');

//Loop through elements and add an event listener to call sendMsg
for(i=0;i<elts.length;i++) {
    elts[i].addEventListener('click',sendMsg,false);
}
```

The reason I have preference of the first solution, is that the `sendMsg` function needs to be changed in the second solution. This would not be possible in all situations, such as using a function from an external js script.